# Solving equation $\tan(z) = 2i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve equation $\tan(z) = 2i$ in set of complex numbers.

**My work so far**

Let's rewrite $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ using imaginary unit:

$$\sin(z) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$\cos(z) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Out of these facts we have that $$\tan(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)} = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}} \cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}} \cdot\frac{1}{2} = 2i$$

$$\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}} = 4i$$

$$e^{ix} - e^{-ix}  = 4ie^{ix} + 4ie^{-ix} \;\;\;\; /\cdot e^{ix}$$

$$e^{2ix} - 1 = 4ie^{2ix} + 4i$$

Let $t := e^{2ix}$, then:

$$t  - 1 = 4it + 4i$$

$$t(1 - 4i) = 4i+ 1 \;\;\;\; /\cdot (1 + 4i)$$

$$17t = (4i+1)(1-4i)\;\;\;\;\; /:17$$

$$t = \frac{(4i+1)(1-4i)}{17}$$

$$e^{2iz} = \frac{(4i+1)(1-4i)}{17}$$

$$2iz = \ln(\frac{(4i+1)(1-4i)}{17}) + 2k\pi\;\;\;\; /\cdot (-i)$$

$$z = -i \ln(\frac{(4i+1)(1-4i)}{17}) - k\pi i$$

Could you please check if my way of thinking is correct? I'm not sure if my result is satisfying even if it's correct because I didn't show $z$ in form of $z = x + iy$.

Comment: We have $sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$ so for $\cos z$ and also $tg(z) = \frac{sin(z)}{cos(z)} = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}} \cdot\frac{1}{2}$ would be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

We have,

$$\tan (z) = 2i\iff \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}= -2$$

$$  \iff 3e^{iz}=-e^{-iz} \iff 3e^{2iz}=-1 \iff 3e^{-2y}e^{2ix}=-1$$

that is:

- $3e^{-2y}=1$
- $2x=\pi + 2k\pi$

Comment: I'm not sure about the first equality that you wrote. For me $$tg(z) = 2i \Leftrightarrow \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}  = 2i \Leftrightarrow \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}  \cdot i = -2i$$

Comment: @Lucian We have $$\tan(z) = 2i \Leftrightarrow \frac{\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}2}  = 2i \Leftrightarrow \frac 1i \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}  = 2i \Leftrightarrow \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}  = -2$$

Comment: Ohhh...you're right! Thanks!

Comment: @Lucian You are welcome! Let me know if some step is not clear yet. Bye